# Is any $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$-function the product of two $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$-functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, smooth-functions

Let $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Are we able to write $$f=gh$$ for some $g,h\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$? Unfortunately, I've no idea how to I could prove or disprove this.

Comment: We can find $g \in C_c(\Bbb R)$ such that $g=1 $on $\text{supp}\ f$ by Urysohn lemma.

Comment: @Song I didn't intend to write "for some $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$" (which is not even a meaningful sentence), but "for some $g,h\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$".

Comment: I didn't recognize it was $C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$, sorry. But we can take care of it by convoluting $g$ with smooth function $\eta$ with support in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and $\int \eta =1$. You can see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) on mollifier and smooth cut-off function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a smooth compactly supported function $g$ that is $1$ on an open ball containing the support of $f$. Then $f=fg$.

For the definition of $g$: let $h(r)=0$ if $r \leq 0$ and $h(r)=e^{-1/r}$ if $r > 0$. It is well-known that $h$ is smooth. Let $h_1(r)=\frac{h(r)}{h(r)+h(1-r)}$: $h_1$ is smooth, zero on $(-\infty,0]$ and $1$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Take now $g(x)=h_1\left(2-\frac{|x|^2}{R^2+1}\right)$ where $\{f \neq 0\} \subset \mathcal{B}(0,R)$.